# Power bi report - DateTime.localNow() doesn't work as supposed

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have some troubles using "DateTime.LocalNow() when I use that I get following 20/08/2020 16.00. This is as supposed and what I want. However, when I publish my report in power bi service and do a manually refresh the date and time has suddenly changed to 8/20/2020 2.00 PM.

So not only is it changing from 24/h to 12/h but it is also 2 hours behind my time zone.

Why is that? I hope you guys can help me, because it is misleading for the users of the report.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The function returns a datetime value set to the current date and time on the system.

Your system and the server you are publishing to are on different timezones. Same as how when it's 8:30 AM in Los Angeles, it's 4:30 PM in London.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a forced FORMAT on your date time value using a measure. Create a measure as below-

```
date_time = FORMAT(NOW(),"dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

Now use this measure in your report and try with publishing the report. You can also try with DateTime.LocalNow() in place I use NOW() in my measure.

> **SOLUTION:**

Here below is the output from different transformation of DateTime value-

[image]

**Step-1:** is the output of your below M/Power Query code.

```
original date = DateTimeZone.SwitchZone(DateTimeZone.LocalNow(),2,0)
```

**Step-2:** Just duplicate the "original date" column and give name "GMT+2". Then change Type if this column to datetime as shown below-

[image]

**Step-3:** Create a Measure in your table (I guess table name - "**DateTimeFormat**")

```
date_formatted = FORMAT(CONVERT(min(DateTimeFormat[GMT+2]),DATETIME),"dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

This above measure should give you your expected output.

Comment: Thank you. It is still doing the same with the the time, but the date format is as supposed now. Do you know if it is possible to add 2 hours to the formula. Like duration +2 or something

Comment: That will be not a good decision. Try to solve it by time zone. This is probably related to server location. Server location can be changed anytime in future. So you can not keep this manual changes for every time server changed. Hope you got my point.

Comment: I get you point however this is only a temporary solution. What I have done now is following - DateTimeZone.SwitchZone(DateTimeZone.LocalNow(),2,0) now the time works, but not the date format as you solved before. Do you know how I can add that into it? Again thank you

Comment: Now it is 12 hours instead of 24 hours

Comment: Provide 3 value here, Your input date, what you are getting, what you want.

Comment: I use DateTimeZone.SwitchZone(DateTimeZone.LocalNow(),2,0) and I am getting 8/21/2020 3.40 PM. The time is now fine, but i want it to be 21/8/2020 15.40

Comment: Hi @JBL, please check the possible solution provided in the answer.